# value in a div javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ask for help because I have hours with this and I can not do it ...

I have several select option:

```
<select name="type" id="type">
        <option value='0'></option>
    <option value='facebook'>Like Fanpage</option>
        <option value='youtube'>Suscriber</option>
        <option value='twitter'>Follow</option>
        <option value='pinterest'>Pin</option>
```

Depending on the value chosen in the select, this js code makes some data or other.

```
 $('#type').on('click',function(e){
 var b=$('#type').val();
 if(b=='0'){
     $('#contenido1').hide()
 }else{
     $('#load').show();
     $.get('contenido/'+b+'/add.php'
```

In this way the code works perfectly and does what I want, the problem is when I want to modify.
I need to replace the  for

```
  <div id="type">

<div value="facebook">facebook</div>
<div value="youtube">youtube</div>
<div value="twitter">twitter</div>
<div value="pinterest">pinterest</div>
```

The problem is esque to replace this way and only works to the line :, $ ('# load') show ().; The following line of code is this: $ .get ('content /' + b + '/ add.php' no longer charge.

The problem is it only works until the line :, $ ('# load') show ().; The following line of code is this: $ .get ('content /' + b + '/ add.php' dont work.

I've read you can not get the variable "value" of a div, and not whether it will be making not get the value of the div,
Could anyone help me solve it?

A greeting and thanks.

Comment: You're sure you're not just asking why the event handler doesn't work on dynamically loaded content? Also, you should be using the `change` event, not `click`

Comment: You're getting `.val()` of a div and that's going to be blank. So the `$.get()` is calling 'contenido//add.php'. If you want to get the value for the div like you have you can use `.attr('value')`

Comment: Another confusion is you have the same id on a `<select>` and a `<div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is never use `click` handler on a `<select>` , it will fire several times during the selection ... to open the select and then when user makes a choice.

Always use `change`.

It is not clear at all what your `$.get` is supposed to do since there is no callback shown for it

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.

After $.get everything works properly, so I removed the code that does not matter.

The problem is in the <div> that although set value = " "  , javascript code dont detected value.

Comment: well is confusing when you have a div and a select with same id... ID's must be unique. Not totally clear what isn't working either

Answer (score 0):

you need change your Click with change and get value of option with attribute selected.

```
 $('#type').on('change',function(e){
     var b=$(this).children("option:selected").val();
 if(b=='0'){
     $('#contenido1').hide()
 }else{
     $('#load').show();
 }
     alert(b);
 });
```

Comment: why not `var b=$(this).val()`?

Comment: i use this mode because in the past with only $(this).val() i have problems with IE8 and IE7.

Comment: Have never had a problem...even in IE6 when jQuery was fairly new. `$('select').val()` was common all the way back to jQuery 1.0